# Getting Wrong data in Date query

Tags: mysql

[image]

Using this query I want only above three data but getting four data

```
SELECT *
FROM `sss_experience_master` `e`
WHERE `e`.`experience_start_time` >= '2018-01-09'
AND `e`.`experience_end_time` <= '2018-01-09'
ORDER BY `e`.`category_id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Your query has a typo.  Please post the actual query you used.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `sss_experience_master` `e`
WHERE `e`.`user_id` != '6'
AND `e`.`status` != '1'
AND `e`.`is_deleted` != '1'
AND `e`.`category_id` IN('37', '39', '46', '44', '41', '40', '42', '38', '33', '30', '47', '36', '34', '45', '31', '43', '35')
AND `e`.`user_id` != '6'
AND `e`.`experience_cost` >= '50'
AND `e`.`experience_cost` <= '2500'
AND `e`.`experience_start_time` >= '2018-01-09'
AND `e`.`experience_start_time` <=  '2018-01-09'
ORDER BY `e`.`category_id` ASC
 LIMIT 10

Comment: Your logic is equivalent to saying `e.experience_start_time >= '2018-01-09 00:00:00'` and, from what I see, should be returning _zero_ records.

Comment: sorry i m new in mysql.. i want just above three record weather end date is zero or not.. i want data between 2018-01-09 this days ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no wrong with your query.

Check the value of your database, search on table "sss_experience_master" look for the column "experience_end_time".

Check if it has a value.

Comment: yes its working when the value is not zero but not working when the value is zero

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query for getting outpot

```
SELECT * FROM sss_experience_master e WHERE 
         e.experience_start_time >= '2018-01-09' AND 
         e.experience_end_time < '2018-01-10' 
    ORDER BY e.category_id ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @Neetin619 This query should be working, and you should post a reproducible question.

Comment: yes its working when the value is not zero but not working when the value is zero for date